# retracting an upvote no longer works

Tags: support, voting, upvotes, grace-period, locked-votes

I up-voted an answer and later decided that I decided to retract the upvote. It seemed that this was possible in the past, but today this was not allowed. Has the policy on upvote retraction been changed?

Since it has been a while since I retracted an upvote, I clicked the downvote by mistake, then realized I need to "undo" the upvote by clicking upvote a second time. Regardless, it did not work.

The message I saw was something like: I upvoted less than 5 minutes ago and no change is allowed unless the answer is edited.

Comment: When you tried to reverse the vote you got an error message telling you exactly what's going on.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, but it tells you exactly *why* it doesn't work.  Why are you asking us when you have a message that has *already explained it to you*.

Comment: Please read the question and you will understand. The question is about policy.

Comment: And that policy is explained in the message you received.

Comment: May be you need to read the question again.

Comment: maybe you need to read the error message again.

Comment: If the policy is unchanged, this could be a bug because I remember it used to work, even after, perhaps hours before the attempted retraction.

Comment: @Servy there is exactly one sentence in this posting with a question mark. You haven't answered it. I hope this answers your inquiry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Votes are locked in after a short amount of time. A new revision to a post unlocks the vote again.

In other words, you can only retract a vote in a grace period that lasts a few (5-ish, but deliberately unspecified) minutes, or if the post was edited.

This has been the policy [for a few years now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted).